# Getting data from mongoose on server but an empty array in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

When I try to return a data from moongoose using React it just display an empty array using a `useEffect` and it return the data when I change something inside the page , also when I try to map the data, it shows nothing :

**server side:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Partner = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    website: { type: String },
},
    { collection: 'partner-data' }
);

const partnerModal = mongoose.model('partner-data', Partner);

module.exports = partnerModal;


app.get('/getpar', (req, res) => {
    Partner.find().then(result => res.send(result)).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

**client side :**

```
const [par, setPar] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        async function getPartners() {
            const req = await axios.get("http://localhost:1200/getpar");
            setPar(req.data);
            console.log(par);
        }

        getPartners();
    },[])

{par.map(p => {p.name})}
```

The server side is working fine, it displays the data when I recall it but when I console log inside the client side it shows an empty array and it doesn't display any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "console logging" before React has updated the `state`. In fact updating a `state` is an `asynchronous` task. To be sure that you are getting the data, do this in `getPartners`:

```
console.log(req.data);
```

And outside your `useEffect` somewhere, do:

```
console.log(par);
```

Comment: oh i didn't know that , thank you its working